# I want to highlight Form complete option in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Actually after filling all the cells in Excel sheet form I want to show it as Form complete, otherwise show it as Form incomplete
I want to write a formula for that please help me to complete this task
Please do help me
Thank you in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcW25.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula to show status message if any of cell is blank in specified range. Try-

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A3:G20)>0,"Form Incomplete","Form Complete")
```

Adjust range `A3:G20` based on data to your excel sheet.